# Is there any need of two 'and's in this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

Is there any need of two *and*s in this sentence?

> The so called Rational Supernaturalism admits the supernatural revelation in holy scripture, **and** puts reason alongside of it as an equally legitimate source of religious knowledge, **and** maintains the rationality of the contents of revelation.
>   <sub>Source: [*Church history* by Kurtz, J. H. (Johann Heinrich), 1809-1890; Macpherson, John; p.196](https://archive.org/stream/churchhistory03kurt#page/196/mode/2up)</sub>

Comment: at times, *need* depends on the *style*!

Comment: You could indeed remove the first _and_, and the sentence would still be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several commenters have pointed out, the answer to your question is: ***no***. In this particular case, the two *and* are assisting the commas in separating the elements of a series. The first *and* is superfluous, thus we could remove it without violating any rules of grammar.

Asif Iqbal's comment, however, brings up an interesting example (contentiously ascribed to Albert Einstein):

> Two things are infinite, the universe and human stupidity, and I am not yet completely sure about the former.

In this case, we have two *and* words but they are performing different roles: the first separates the elements of a binary series; the second, however, is a conjunction for an independent clause.